# Define publish folder per project when publishing whole solution with dotnet publish

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have a C# dotnet core solution and it contains many projects. Then I want to publish my solution to distribute my build application.

When I run `dotnet publish -o publish/win1064 -r win10-x64` in a folder with the sln file (I'm using dotnet core sdk 3.1), all build artifacts (dlls) are stored in the publish/win1064 folder. I want to have some projects to be published in a subfolders, like publish/win1064/plugins/pluginA for a project "pluginA" for example.

I can do it by running the `dotnet publish` for every project and set the output folder accordingly, but is there any way to do it with a one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a safe way of invoking `dotnet publish` at solution level, I would strongly advise you not to do it. You can find [other answers stating the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52687226/5459321) out there.

That's why most CI tools allow you to use some kind of wildcards (i.e., `**/*.csproj`) to run `dotnet` commands over multiple projects, but not at solution level.

You'd face similar issues if you try to run tests at solution level and collect coverage/test results from that. (i.e. `dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=./CoverageResults`).